# 'pip install flask_mysqldb' fails with error message 'exit status 2'

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to install 'flask_mysqldb' for my backend Python project. I installed Microsoft Visual C++ and the latest supported Visual C++ download from this source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads.

However, when I try to run 'pip install flask_mysqldb' in Git Bash, I get error message:

`_mysql.c
    _mysql.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\myNAme\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2`

I have to point that when installing Microsoft Visual C++, the installer runs fine, but I do not get an success (or any other kind of) message when it finishes. It just dissappears.

What could be the cause of the issue? Maybe Visual C++ is not installed at all? If so, how can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install [MySQL development libraries](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/).

And you might want to consult also [MySQLdb troubleshooting guide](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/FAQ.html#build-errors).

MySQLdb is a underlying library used by Flask-MySQLdb.

Comment: Thanks, does having XAMPP means that this is already taken care of?

Comment: @IsaaK08 I guess not, usually the development stuff (usually headers) need to be installed separately. And to make things even more complicated, recent XAMPP actually installs MariaDB instead of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler says: you don't have the requisite headers (`mysql.h`) installed or maybe you do, but they are definitely not on the include path (`-I` flags or whatever the `cl.exe` equivalent is).

You will want to revisit the installation instructions for the `flask_mysqldb` package carefully and make sure you have your environment set up correctly.